# PHP post without curl wait for response

Tags: php, post

Doing a PHP call without cURL (as found here: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/), but the response will take about 10-15 seconds to come back. It currently just comes up with an error. Any idea how to get this working? I've tried set_time_limit to no avail.

Code:

```
function DoPostRequest($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
    $params = array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'content' => $data));
    if($optional_headers != null) {
        $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
    }
    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    try {
        $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
        $response = stream_get_contents($fp);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'Exception: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
    return $response;
}
```

And the error:

```
Notice: fopen(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded in <php url> on line 81 Warning: fopen(http://localhost:59396/Update.ashx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 100 Continue in <php url> on line 81 Warning: stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <php url> on line 82 bool(false)
```

Comment: What is the error that appears?

Comment: Please see edit. I've slightly changed the code to show full error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
function DoPostRequest($url, $data, $optional_headers = null) {
    $params = array (
            'http' => array (
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'content' => $data,
                    'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
                    "Content-Length: " . strlen ( $data ) . "\r\n" 
            ) 
    );
    if ($optional_headers != null) {
        $params ['http'] ['header'] = $optional_headers;
    }
    $ctx = stream_context_create ( $params );
    try {
        $fp = fopen ( $url, 'rb', false, $ctx );
        $response = stream_get_contents ( $fp );
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage ();
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Change Content-Type to what you want .. JSON, XML anything